# Kombu Exception Content Disallowed

Tags: celery, kombu

Whenever celery is getting a task to run I am getting an exception

`Pool callback raised exception: ContentDisallowed('Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fulfil/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'chord'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fulfil/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: '_payload'`

I am using Celery==4.1.1 (latentcall) and kombu==4.2.1 version
can someone please help me out.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the exact same problem.